# Accessing a templated functions in a derived class via a base pointer

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

Here is an abstraction of my problem.

I want to develop something like this.

```
class Base {
}

template<typename T>
class TypedBase : Base {

    f(const T& input);
}
```

Now I Want to access the "family" of classes TypedBase via a base pointer and call f.

Something like this

```
Base* base_ptr;
if (condition) {
  base_ptr = new TypedBase<double>();
} else {
  base_ptr = new TypedBase<int>();
}

// Int and double are just examples to get the idea
// Then I Want to call

base_ptr->f(4);
```

This won't compile.

I tried to add an empty virtual function f() to base hoping that vtable would take care of calling the right f() vs. f(T& input) at run time but again didn't work like:

```
class Base {
   virtual f() = 0;
}
```

So how do you do that? in general I want to have a pointer to a generic TypedBase that allows me to call f(...) via a generic pointer to the family. Any thoughts?

Of course I could do this:

```
class Base {
    // Repeat for every typename
    virtual f(int& x) = 0;
    virtual f(double& x) = 0;
}
```

and then each TypedBase will only implements one of them thus I will still get type safety at run time without doing dynamic checking myself in the code. However, If I have N functions to call and M types to work with, then I will have to add M*N abstract functions to the Base class. Any better solution?

Comment: If `p` is a `Base` pointer that actually points to `TypedBase<double>, and you call `p->f("foo")`, what do you want to happen?

Comment: Why is there no syntax highlighting?? that's weird...

Answer (score 1):

You must `static_cast` (if you know the real type) or `dynamic_cast` (if you need to check if cast succeeded) the base pointer to right class. If you know what you are passing to method, casting to type that takes that argument should not be a problem. Also casting should work in a template method with right template type.

Does following compile?

```
template <typename T>
void callF(Base *p, T input) {
  TypedBase<T> *tp = dynamic_cast<TypedBase<T>*>(p);
  if (tp) tp->f(input);
  // else throw exception or call some Base method or return error or...
}
```

Or less safe, just do:

```
static_cast<TypedBase<int>*>(base_ptr)->f(1);
```